# How to drop multiple tables with prefix

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a database db1 containing many table

- v1_tab_1
- ...
- v1_tab_n
- v2_tab_1
- ...
- v2_tab_n

For exemple, I would like to drop all tables with prefix v1_ 
something like

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS v1_*;
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You could do it with dynamic SQL and build the delete queries on-the-fly. Having a lot of tables to delete smells like a design flaw. Maybe you should redesign.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible to do with Athena SQL.

You can, however, use the Glue API to achieve something similar, for example through [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws glue get-tables \
  --region us-east-1 \
  --database-name my_database \
  --query 'TableList[].Name' \
  --output text \
  | grep -F v1_ \
  | xargs -n 1 aws glue delete-table \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --database-name my_database \
    --name
```

The command above lists all tables in a database called "my_database" in the us-east-1 region, and filters them by "v1_" (you might want to filter by regex to ensure that it only matches in the beginning). It then pipes the matching table names, one by one, into a command that deletes them.

Comment: This deleted all the tables in my database, also, in this example any table that contains v1_ will be removed it does not necessarily look for it as a prefix.